# Получение значений полей django при one to many

Tags: django

При попытке отображения поля в шаблоне не выводится необходимая информация.
Модели:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post')
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User') 

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
```

Часть templat-а
post-обьект класса Post.К этому обьекту в админке добавлен Comment

```
<div class="comment"><h1>{{ post.comment.text}}</h1></div>
```

Comment: почитайте про атрибут related_name для полей связи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как пост у Вас один, а комментариев много, вы не можете прямо обратится к тексту комментария (Вы то понимаете, что первого, но явно это не указано), только к списку комментариев:

```
    {% for comment in post.comment_set.all %}
        <div class="comment"><h1>{{ comment.text}}</h1></div>
    {% endfor %}
```

[дока](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)

Answer (score 0):

Новички часто с этим путаются.
Поле ForeignKey определяет отношение многие_к_одному, а не один_ко_многим.
То есть с учётом написанного вами кода, будет много `Comment` у одного `Post`.
Это значит, что доступ выглядит:

```
<div class="comment"><h1>{{ comment.post.text}}</h1></div>
```